# Child tasks are not awaited by parent task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

This is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Thing> collection = new List<Thing>
    { 
        new Thing { IntProp = 1, BoolProp = true }, 
        new Thing { IntProp = 1, BoolProp = true }, 
        new Thing { IntProp = 2, BoolProp = true }, 
        new Thing { IntProp = 1, BoolProp = false } 
    };

    int number = 0;

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
    {
        TaskFactory ts = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item.BoolProp)
            {
                ts.StartNew(() =>
                    number += GetNum1(item.IntProp));
            }
            else
            {
                ts.StartNew(() =>
                    number += GetNum2(item.IntProp));
            }
        }

        return true;
    });

    task.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

here is are definitions of `GetNum1` and `GetNum2`

```
static int GetNum1(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) { } // simulate some job

    return 10;
}

static int GetNum2(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++) { } // simulate some job

    return 3;
}
```

and here is the `Thing` class

```
class Thing
{
    public bool BoolProp { get; set; }
    public int IntProp { get; set; }
}
```

basically what I am doing is just creating the collection of `Thing` objects. then I create a single parent task which will have several child task (which it should await, I guess).

there is a `number` variable which is incremented by child task by the amount returned from  `GetNum1` and `GetNum2` method (10 or 3). the code above should output 33 (10 + 10 + 10 + 3) as I guess, but 10 is outputted instead, Because just the first child task is awaited. If I put the breakpoint in the code and go step by step than the output is correct. Why does this happen. does it have to do something with the foreach loop inside the parent task ? Please do not start asking question like "why you need this" and "there is no need for that", this is just an example code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent task is in fact waiting for (not "awaiting") the child tasks. Your problem is that the code is accessing the `number` variable from multiple threads without synchronization:

```
var mutex = new object();
int number = 0;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
{
    TaskFactory ts = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (item.BoolProp)
        {
            ts.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var value = GetNum1(item.IntProp);
                lock (mutex) number += value;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            ts.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var value = GetNum2(item.IntProp);
                lock (mutex) number += value;
            });
        }
    }

    return true;
});

task.Wait();

lock (mutex)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Recommended reading: [Parallel Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx) and [Dynamic Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx).

Comment: I tried without the **lock (mutex)** before the Console.WriteLine() still can have result 33 also

Comment: @V-SHY: Skipping the `lock` on a read sometimes works but thread-local caches can mess you up on advanced hardware.